# Unity - InControl How do I detect one Action push?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, assets

I have a question on user input for a Unity Plug-in. I am using InControl and got everything setup. I'm testing when I hold down an Action button (A,B,X,Y or Cross,Square,Triangle,Circle) it should only print once that the button was pressed. Except it loops the print message. I might be able to figure it out if there's a method to see if the Action button was let go but there's absolutely nothing in the source or online for letting go of the buttons or holding them. Any help?

Researched online and even looked through InControl scripts and could not find any methods related to holding or letting a button up.

```
InputDevice controller1;

void Start ()
{
  controller1 = InputManager.Devices[0]; //or InputManager.ActiveDevice
}

void Update ()
{
  if (controller1.Action1)
  {
    Debug.Log("Controller button A pressed");
    //constantly loops this Log instead of only executing once
  }
}
```

The Log should only print once if you hold down an Action button.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Please refer to this InControl docs :

http://www.gallantgames.com/pages/incontrol-getting-started

If you scroll a bit down the page you will see this list :

```
control.IsPressed;   // bool, is currently pressed

control.WasPressed;  // bool, pressed since previous tick

control.WasReleased; // bool, released since previous tick

control.HasChanged;  // bool, has changed since previous tick

control.State;       // bool, is currently pressed (same as IsPressed)

control.Value;       // float, in range -1..1 for axes, 0..1 for buttons / triggers

control.LastState;   // bool, previous tick state

control.LastValue;   // float, previous tick value
```

Hoper this helps cheers.